# GSON ClassCast Exception cannot cast from object to string

Tags: java, gson

```
        List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
        l.add("abc");
        String s = (String) l.get(0); /////// No Exception here
        System.out.println(l); 
        String json = gson.toJson(l);
        System.out.println(json);
        Type t = new TypeToken<List<Object>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<Object> dl = gson.fromJson(json, t);
        String ds = (String) dl.get(0); /////Class Cast Exception here
```

Doing something like the above one. I am trying to serialize a list of Objects. First element in that is a String, but when I deserialized the list and reading the first element to a string it's throwing a classcastexception. And there are no exceptions when reading the first element to a string before serializing.

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Have you stepped through this code line-by-line to see what might be gling on?

Comment: Give the EXACT and COMPLETE error message.  And show us the JSON.

Comment: This is the error message:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: If you have an `Object`, that did not come from JSON.  (Unless GSON uses `Object` as a "null" value or some such -- I'm not up on all the various JSON kits and their quirks.)  Again, where is the JSON?

Comment: I don't get any error when running this code. Which version of Gson are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an older version of GSON 1.4.

Updating it to 2.2.4 version worked.